# how to save the pattern you search for in perl

Tags: perl

```
if ($_=~m/^[\w](.+)\n/)
{
   $seq.= $1;
}
```

I am using this pattern to recognise a character sequence but I also want to include the first character (the [\w])

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the first character, include it into the capturing part of the regex:

```
$seq .= $1 if /^(\w.+)\n/;
```

Answer (score 1):

The parens determine what ends up in `$1`, so you want

```
if ($_=~m/^([\w].+)\n/)
{
   $seq.= $1;
}
```

This simplifies to

```
$seq .= $1 if /^(\w.+\n)/;
```

You probably meant `.*` (0 or more non-linefeed) instead of `.+` (1 or more non-linefeed).

```
$seq .= $1 if /^(\w.*)\n/;
```

I'd write that as follows:

```
chomp;
$seq .= $_ if /^\w/;
```

This last one is not strictly equivalent.

- It doesn't check if the second character of `$_` is a non-linfeed.
- It doesn't check if `$_` contains a line feed.
- If `$_` contains a line feed, it's expected to be the last character of the string.
- `$_` is modified.